# PSexec with /timeout and /min

Tags: batch-file, psexec

Can someone help me with this command? I basically want PSEXEC to execute a batch file in minimised mode, then shut it down after 100 seconds. I've had complaints that PSEXEC is too obtrusive to the remote users. They want it hidden and to close down itself.

Currently I have this to start PSEXEC and call the batch file:

```
  psexec -i -s \\YOURPC \\YOURPC\alert.cmd
```

`alert.cmd` is a follows:

```
start /min cmd /k "echo Hello world" /timeout /t 100
```

This works without time out, but I can't figure out how to get the timer working on the `alert.cmd`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
start /min cmd /k "echo Hello world && timeout /t 100"
```

Comment: FYI - I had to add '&& Exit' to the end to kill it :)